# Filtring function with angular 2 tree component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement angular2-tree component

https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/filtering

So far everything is good I want just to use the filtering feature and i don't know how to activate it.

Here's my code:

**app.component.ts**

```js
    import { Component ,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
    import {OdooRPCService } from 'angular2-odoo-jsonrpc';
    import {
      TreeComponent,
      TreeNode,
      TREE_ACTIONS,
      KEYS,
      IActionMapping
    } from 'angular2-tree-component';

    export class ResPartner {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      buyerTree: number[];
    }

    export class ProductCategory {
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: 'tree.component.html',
      providers: [ OdooRPCService],

    })
    export class AppComponent   { 
       // @ViewChild('tree') tree: any;
       @ViewChild(TreeComponent)
       private tree: TreeComponent;

       constructor(public odooRPC: OdooRPCService) {  
          // I construct my tree here 
       }
    }
```

**tree.component.html**

```html
<input #filter (keyup)="filterNodes(filter.value, tree)" placeholder="filter nodes" />
<br/>
<Tree #tree (onMoveNode)="onMoveNode($event)" [focused]="true" [nodes]="nodes" [options]="customTemplateStringOptions">
<!--<Tree [nodes]="nodes">-->
  <template #treeNodeTemplate let-node>
   <!--<button (click)="af($event)">AF</button> 
   <button (click)="ab($event)">AB</button> 
   <button (click)="sf($event)">SF</button> 
   <button (click)="sb($event)">SB</button>   -->
   <span><img src="{{node.data.person == '1' ? 'app/user.png' : 'app/catg.png'}}" />{{ node.data.name }}</span>
      <!--<button (click)="sb($event)">APPEL</button>   
      <button (click)="sb($event)">Email</button>   -->
  </template>
</Tree>**
```

But when i use my input to search throw my tree i get this error:

```
core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/tree.component.html:1:0 caused by: self.context.filterNodes is not a function

core.umd.js:3493 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.context.filterNodes is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for the answer

```
    export class AppComponent   { 
       // @ViewChild('tree') tree: any;
       @ViewChild(TreeComponent)
       private tree: TreeComponent;

       constructor(public odooRPC: OdooRPCService) {  
          // I construct my tree here 
       }

      filterNodes(text, tree)                      {
         tree.treeModel.filterNodes(text, true);
       }
 }
```

In fact there's an example on the repo of the project:
[https://github.com/500tech/angular2-tree-     component/tree/master/example/cli/src/app](http://component/tree/master/example/cli/src/app)

We can find and exemple on the *app.component.ts*